# I am using ajax call for calling api it is working fine in Localhost but it is not working in server(showing 404 not found)

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/active/get-url',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    data: {
        siteid: siteid,
        sno: ids
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if (data.length > 0) {
            rawdataIp = data[0].IP;
            rawdataIp = rawdataIp.slice(7);
            url = rawdataIp;
            console.log("urlll" + url);
            videourl = rawdataIp;
        }
        imageDisplay(url);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is likely not a client issue, but a server issue.  You need to make sure that the server is actually successfully handling the request URL you are sending the Ajax call to.  What kind of server is it?

Comment: Can you paste the error log from browser console like Firebug? More likely is a CORS issue. If so please mention the server technology stack.